# Importing functions causing "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

Tags: python, discord.py

Since discord.py 2.0 and the addition of "asyncio.run(main())":
When loading extensions, my extension file imports functions from the main file which gives the error "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" Any ideas on how to fix this, why its happening, or ways to work around it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tehPZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

See [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for some more info.